# StreamBuilder used for other than gridview or listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make filter chips based on data from firestore using StreamBuilder. I have recieved the data from firebase, just need to make them into filter chips.

Comment: the filter chips would depend on the input of the user? or just show all the data in different chips?

Comment: Just show the data in different chips

Answer (score 0):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html

this link should help you in adding the checkbox and all and then instead of the `text` use your `streamBuilder` data for the `Text Widget.`

Comment: I'd like the number filter chips based on the number of documents received not hard coded

Comment: use a ```for``` loop to create your list using the document count as the counter. and put this into the app init state so that whenever the app is started this list is created first